# Specific questions: Statistical tests, fair analysis

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics, image-processing

**Background:** My dataset is small (3 to 10 values). But each set comes from 18 acquisitions of different areas of the same sample. So they would not be considered independent. But 3-10 values are too small to analyze whether the distribution is normal. And the raw values differ a lot between independent experiments but we express them as percentage of the 'control' and then are very comparable.

**Questions:**

1. We measure the background noise in our experiment and subtract it from each dataset. Does this skew the standard deviation of the samples? Should it not be subtracted?
2. Is it fair to test our sample against the control which will always be 100%?
3. Also, although I can calculate the standard deviation of the control within each independent experiment, how can I express the standard deviation between independent experiments? I'm sure you can't just average the standard deviations!
4. For comparing one sample to the control, is the Wilcoxon signed rank test reasonable for such a non-parametric low sample data set? Can we compare it to the hypothetical value of 100%?
5. For comparing a sample treated with increasing doses of a chemical (multiple datasets), is the Kruskall Walis test a reasonable one? Can it also be compared to the hypothetical value of 100%?

Comment: Can you say more about what your data are? How are they gathered / measured? What is the "background noise"? How is it assessed? etc.

Comment: I didnt think it was relevant for statistical purposes. They are microscope images of infected cells: 6 images from three independent wells (6x3=18 images per experiment). Intensity values are measured. Background noise are wells that were not infected. Does this help?

Comment: Intuitively, people typically don't think it's relevant, but in reality, it pretty much always is. So you have 6 images each from 3 different infected cells, & you are calculating the mean intensity of each image; furthermore, you are calculating the mean intensity from each image from a set of images of non-infected cells, is that right? For the non-infected cells, is it 1 image per cell? How many non-infected cell images do you have? What is your hypothesis, that the mean intensity of infected cells is larger than the mean intensity of non-infected cells?

Comment: I dont plan to factor in the number of cells. Per experiment, per sample: there are 3 repeats. Each repeat consists of 6 images, 6x3=18. The image per se contains 200-400 cells, since image dimensions are fairly constant the number of cells is constant in each image even from different samples. I don't plan to test the hypothesis of whether the mean intensity of infected cells is larger than uninfected, biologically i do not need statistics to support that statement. But I want to test the hypothesis if infected cells treated with a chemical have a lower mean intensity than just infected cells